# Blinking dash when booting Windows 7 on Eee

Tags: windows-7, boot, troubleshooting, installation, eee-pc

I just got a new faster SSD for my Asus eee 900 and figured I'd take the opportunity to try Windows 7 on it. I did the magic to get the install DVD to a usb-stick and it installed just fine.

However, once it reboots to go into Windows all I get is a blinking dash in the upper left corner.

It's hard to tell if it's doing anything, but the disk led doesn't blink, and I've left it running for a couple of hours to no avail. 
If I run the diagnostics that come with the installer everything checks out fine. I've also tried reinstalling a second time and I get the same problem.

How do I find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrmmph, I don't think there's any way of knowing, but...

It looks like your computer is executing the master boot record made by Win7 and it fails somewhere early on (incompatibility btwn EEE, Win7). Probably you need a BIOS update to make it compatible.

Comment: it took me the better part of the afternoon to get a new bios in (the newer bios versions failed silently using the asus linked version of AFUDOS, but when i got a more recent version(2.36) it finally worked.